# How to mount Daemon Tool's .mdx file?

Tags: 10.10, mount, iso

How to mount a Windows' Daemon Tool's .mdx file in Ubuntu?

The scenario is you don't have Windows and want to access the files in .mdx image on Ubuntu.

Comment: i don't have an mdx file to test with, but is it a possibility that .mdx(daemon tools) is just a clone of the .mdf(alcohol 120) format?  mdf2iso handles converting mdf to whatever standard format you like...i would try renaming the mdx to mdf and giving it a go...

Comment: Can you give the output of "file <yourfile>" (without quotes, and in the Terminal)?  I don't have an mdx file to test either, but this at least gives some information about it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, here: 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ file myMDX.mdx 
myMDX.mdx: MED_Song
...that's all it displayed.

Comment: Hmmm... I wouldn't know what to do with that.  The only other thing I can think of is, can you install Daemon Tools Lite via WINE and get it to do what you want?  (Even if that's just export it to ISO?)

Comment: I have tried running Daemon Tool installer using WINE, but it yelled back at me "Internal Setup Error. Code 256." in the installer. No, this does not work... I guess the installer is trying to look for something along the line of a place for virtual drive... perhaps? And WINE couldn't handle it?

Answer (score 12):

With the package [**iat**](http://packages.debian.org/unstable/otherosfs/iat), available from the standard repositories, it is possible to convert a `.mdx` file, to an easy mountable `.iso` file.

Comment: Interesting. I will need some sort of test result for this...

Comment: You'd better write the commands to be used. I just want to do the conversion, I don't care about how the package is called, what packages are related and all the stuff. Yes, staying ignorant is fine, sometimes. Luckily, the command is called `iat`, too.

Comment: @maaartinus for Arch Linux I used `iat --iso -i original.mdx -o new.iso` . Not sure whether it is the same for other packages.

Answer (score 5):

```
mount -o loop,offset=64 image.mdx /mnt/cdrom/
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, Could you please explain in a little more detail what this command actually does?

Comment: Does this method really support .mdx images?

Comment: It worked for me.

Comment: This method does not work for password protected *.mdx files created with Daemon Tools.

Comment: Doesn't work for me `wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.` Also, ⁻¹ for lack of explanation *(e.g. why offset is 64, why not 32 or 1024, or whatever?)*.

Comment: Works for me. Make sure to create the mountpoint directory if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CDemu:

https://cdemu.sourceforge.io/about/libmirage/

after installation just run:

`cdemu load 0 your_image.mdx` and it will appear as CD-ROM you can mount.

You can also use GUI of your choice like `gcdemu`.

All of them are available in this PPA: [https://launchpad.net/~cdemu/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecdemu/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)